# k-dissection of a polygon with non-intersecting diagonals

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, polygons

I am trying to use the vertex coalescing method like the one mentioned [here](http://press.princeton.edu/chapters/s9489.pdf), page 10, to count: Number of dissections of a polygon using non-intersecting diagonals into even number of regions.

I am trying to frame a recursion, and I think I have this:

Let $a_{k, n}$ be the number of dissections of an $n$-vertex polygon into $k$ regions.
Then,
For a given number of regions: call it $a_{k, n+1}$, the number of dissections that merge into the same number of regions $k$ for $n$ vertices = (degree of a fixed vertex - $1$) summed over all members of $a_{k, n}$.

Triangles are also coalesced to reduce the number of regions, so I think there is some relation between $a_{k, n+1}$ and $a_{k-1, n}$.

Any idea on how to go about this problem?

Edit:
Any other approaches to solving this problem are also welcome.

Comment: I don't see your relation easily. You want to remove one vertex and one diagonal?

Comment: I want to remove one edge, or coalesce two vertices together, going from n+1 to n.

Comment: The problem is that there are many cases to consider, e.g. removing a vertex without diagonal may decrease the number of regions or not ...